# file in src/main/resources is not in classpath

Tags: java, spring

I created a simple program to check if spring-context define a file in src/main/resources folder.

I have this file structure:

```
project
--> src/main/resources/spring-config.xml
--> src/main/resources/testfile02
```

and I try to access to these files using this test class

```
public class ClasspathTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws URISyntaxException {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:spring-config.xml");

        ClassPathResource testfile02 = new ClassPathResource("classpath:testfile02");

        if (testfile02 != null) {
            try (InputStream inputStream = testfile02.getInputStream();
                Reader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(streamReader)) {
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

And I can't understand why I get FileNotFound exception, during classpathResource.getInputStream() if the ClassPathXmlAppContext is working ok.

execution log:

```
янв 19, 2016 11:57:48 AM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@6193b845: startup date [Tue Jan 19 11:57:48 MSK 2016]; root of context hierarchy
янв 19, 2016 11:57:48 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring-config.xml]
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [classpath:testfile02] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

The project is built using gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
version = '1.0'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.6.RELEASE'
}
```

.classpath:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/resources"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.classpathcontainer"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

I tried to detect systemproperty java.class.path, and I've got {project}/bin and jars for spring there and that's all. No resources folder.
How can I get access to resources from src/main/resources as I get access to src/main/resources/spring-config.xml?

Comment: Is it `testfile01` or `testfile02`? (And did you check `target/classes` or the actual jar contents?)

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake at the question, the name is the same (testfile02), so my question still exists

Comment: How do you run your test? Using maven or gradle or IDE ? Have you set up  `src/main/resources` as a source path ?

Comment: Hello Wim, it's built using gradle, I added build file to the question. The folder src/main/resources is a source path as you can see at .classpath

Comment: Do you need to have the `classpath:` in the constructor argument? Can you try with `new ClassPathResource("testfile02")` ?

Comment: Wim, it's working with no "classpath:" for resource. But could you explain, why is it working for xml and not working for resource? Any of these files (xml and resource) are in /bin/ folder during execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to add the 'classpath:' prefix when using the constructor. This works:

```
public class ClasspathTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws URISyntaxException {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:spring-config.xml");

        ClassPathResource testfile02 = new ClassPathResource("testfile02");

        if (testfile02 != null) {
            try (InputStream inputStream = testfile02.getInputStream();
                Reader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(streamReader)) {
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the vanilla Java which is how you're running it will not add src/main/resources to the classpath, that is a convention that other runners use.

Below works fine.

```
package com.greg;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(value = { "classpath:spring-config.xml",
        "classpath:testfile02.xml" })
public class ClasspathTest {

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "classpath:spring-config.xml");

        ClassPathResource testfile02 = new ClassPathResource("testfile02.xml");

        if (testfile02 != null) {
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = testfile02.getInputStream();
                Reader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream,
                        "UTF-8");
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Has nothing to do with JUnit runners or plain Java. The important bit is removing the 'classpath:' from the constructor argument of `ClassPathResource`.

Comment: I think that your problem definition is right. Anyway these files are in /bin/ folder at running time, and classpath has its folder. As I see ClassPathResource doesn't support "classpath:" prefix as ClassPathXmlApplicationContext do